# Touch screen on ASUS X202E not working properly

Tags: asus, touchscreen

Got a little problem with using my touch screen on ASUS X202E with i3 (the notebook-undervolted version). The thing is: when I touch the screen it perfectly recognizes where I touched it and places a cursor there. Even if I click EXACTLY in the same spot it does NOT interact ("click") on objects.

I also noticed that it works in some apps: I recently closed Steam window by touching the screen.

The question is: is it possible to make touch screen work everywhere? And it would be great if it would "auto-click" where I touch instead of putting a cursor there and after next touch "clicking"?

Thanks for your help! :)

@edit:

Well - it seems to have started working for some reason. Maybe an update of some kind. It works great now! :D